# Error: list indices must be integers, not Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have grabbed a column from a pandas data frame and made a list from the rows.
If I print the first two values of the list, I get this output:

```
print dfList[0]
print dfList[1]

0     0.00
1     0.00
2     0.00
3     0.00
4     0.00
5     0.11
6     0.84
7     1.00
8     0.27
9     0.00
10    0.52
11    0.55
12    0.92
13    0.00
14    0.00
...
50    0.42
51    0.00
52    0.00
53    0.00
54    0.40
55    0.65
56    0.81
57    1.00
58    0.54
59    0.21
60    0.00
61    0.33
62    1.00
63    0.75
64    1.00
Name: 9, Length: 65, dtype: float64
65    1.00
66    1.00
67    1.00
68    1.00
69    1.00
70    1.00
71    0.55
72    0.00
73    0.39
74    0.51
75    0.70
76    0.83
77    0.87
78    0.85
79    0.53
...
126    0.83
127    0.83
128    0.83
129    0.71
130    0.26
131    0.11
132    0.00
133    0.00
134    0.50
135    1.00
136    1.00
137    0.59
138    0.59
139    0.59
140    1.00
Name: 9, Length: 76, dtype: float64
```

When I try to iterate over the list with a for loop, I get an error message:

```
for i in dfList:
    print dfList[i]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./windows.py", line 84, in <module>
    print dfList[i]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Series
```

If I write my code as:

```
for i in dfList:
    print i
```

I get the correct output:

```
0     0.00
1     0.00
2     0.00
3     0.00
4     0.00
5     0.11
6     0.84
7     1.00
8     0.27
9     0.00
10    0.52
11    0.55
12    0.92
13    0.00
14    0.00
...
50    0.42
51    0.00
52    0.00
53    0.00
54    0.40
55    0.65
56    0.81
57    1.00
58    0.54
59    0.21
60    0.00
61    0.33
62    1.00
63    0.75
64    1.00
Name: 9, Length: 65, dtype: float64
...
...
Name: 9, Length: 108, dtype: float64
507919    0.00
507920    0.83
507921    1.00
507922    1.00
507923    0.46
507924    0.83
507925    1.00
507926    1.00
507927    1.00
507928    1.00
507929    1.00
507930    1.00
507931    1.00
507932    1.00
507933    1.00
...
508216    1
508217    1
508218    1
508219    1
508220    1
508221    1
508222    1
508223    1
508224    1
508225    1
508226    1
508227    1
508228    1
508229    1
508230    1
Name: 9, Length: 312, dtype: float64
```

I do not know why this happens.

I ultimately want to iterate through the list for 5 consecutive "windows" and calculate their means and put these means in a list.

Comment: If `dfList` is indeed a DataFrame, your code should have worked @Rodrigo. Are you sure it's a DataFrame? Could you post a sample of how `dfList` was constructed? My guess is that `dfList` is actually an array of `Series`.

Answer (score 2):

In python when you write `for i in` then `i` is the element not the index you need to then `print i` not `print dfList[i]`.

Either of the following two options are fine:

```
for i in dfList[i]:
  print i

for i in range(len(dfList)):
  print dfList[i]
```

The first is more pythonic and elegant unless you need the index.

### Edit

As jwilner suggested you can also do:

```
for i, element in enumerate(dfList):
  print i, element
```

Here `i` is the index and `element` is the `dfList[i]`.

Comment: Even if you need the index, `enumerate(dfList)` is way better.